# Questions about how to use javascript to increase virtual nodes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a set of ui and li structures. Currently, I have a requirement to concatenate the API to form 4 lis of data and put them behind the original li to add! I use the appendChild method, but you need to use this method first Create a node let div = document.createElement('div'); But this will cause the newly created label to add a div, which is a label I don't want. I would like to ask if it is possible to create a virtual empty node and put li in it ? I don't know how to do it specifically, and hope to get your help. I wrote an example such as the following case code to simulate my problem, thank you PS: I have tried to use innerHTML, but this will overwrite the original content when adding data in my actual project, so it does not work .

```js
let str;
let wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');
let div = document.createElement('div');
str += `<li>5555</li>
<li>6666</li>
<li>7777</li>
<li>8888</li>
`

div.innerHTML = str;
wrap.appendChild(div);
```

```html
<ul class="wrap">
  <li>1111</li>
  <li>2222</li>
  <li>3333</li>
  <li>4444</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `for(var i=0; i<div.children.length; i++) wrap.appendChild(div.children[i]);`

Comment: Why are you creating a div here? You know that `<li>` don't go inside a div, they go inside a `<ul>` (or `<ol>`), just put them in `wrap` element? As for not overwriting what's already in there: then don't use strings. Just build `li` elements in the same way you're creating that (not needed) div right now, and add those to your `wrap` element.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans
Let me show you the logic I have written so far, as follows: I have a serial API and store the data returned by the API in str, and then need to put it in the notice_generally container. There are already some li in the container that cannot be overwritten, and can only be placed in elements are added

https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/MWBzMVg?editors=1010

Comment: a virtual empty Node? What is that supposed to mean? The only thing that comes close to it would be a Shadow DOM.

Comment: @tacoshy The DOM has this feature natively, see my answer

Comment: @Bergi It don't just add it virtually, it exists in the DOM afterward. I thought he mean To add something to The DOM that does not really is visible there.

Comment: @tacoshy No, it doesn't exist in the DOM afterwards: "*[…] `append` or `insert` the fragment into the DOM using Node interface methods such as `appendChild()`, `append()`, or `insertBefore()`. Doing this moves the fragment's nodes into the DOM, leaving behind an empty `DocumentFragment`.*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create a virtual empty node and put `<li>` elements in it?

Yes, this exactly what a [`DocumentFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) does. Once you append the fragment to the `<ul>`, the intermediate "virtual" node is skipped and its contents are transferred.

However, a fragment does not have an `.innerHTML` property. For your use case, better use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

```js
const wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');
const str = `<li>5555</li>
<li>6666</li>
<li>7777</li>
<li>8888</li>
`;
wrap.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
```

```html
<ul class="wrap">
  <li>1111</li>
  <li>2222</li>
  <li>3333</li>
  <li>4444</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -2):

You added the `jquery` tag, so I am going to use it because it's easier that way. With jQuery you can add multiple `<li>` tags at once, which is preferred because each DOM update is expensive.

```js
let html = `<li>5555</li>
<li>6666</li>
<li>7777</li>
<li>8888</li>`;
$('.wrap').append(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="wrap">
  <li>1111</li>
  <li>2222</li>
  <li>3333</li>
  <li>4444</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "*it's easier that way*" - I disagree

Comment: JS can do that also by default without needing to run a huge script to run int he background to add something to JS that it already has by default.

Comment: @Bergi: Maybe because you are not used to it?

Comment: @tacoshy: Why complain about jQuery instead of posting an answer with native JS? There is nothing wrong using jQuery in a project that already uses jQuery.

Comment: @PeterThoeny "*jQuery has several advantages over native [DOM]*" - fewer and fewer in modern browsers. "*If [jQuery i]s already used in a project there is no reason to mix in native JS to manipulate the DOM, in fact it makes the code convoluted*" - I would agree with that, but the OP's code in the question doesn't use jQuery either. Tbh I have no idea why they added the [jquery] tag to their question, and would probably remove it if you hadn't already posted an answer.